# Instagram font icon showing as a square

Tags: css, icon-fonts

My footer in Wordpress has a number of social icons, but Instagram is the only one that fails rendering properly (see attached image):

[image]

I have added the following for better font rendering:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

And this is how the icon is defined in my style.css:

```
.icon-instagram:before {
  content: "\e604";
}
```

What is the issue? I am very new to css icons, so I am not sure what the issue can be in this case.

Thank you,

**EDIT1:**

Font-family is defined as follows in my style.css:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  font-family: 'my-icons';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: Which icon font library do you use? probably wrong unicode.

Comment: It is a propertary icon font library. From svg the glyph unicode="&#xe604, so it is correct.

Comment: Have you set font-family to that one? just compare with the working ones.

Comment: @Pangloss, thanks for your help - Have a look at my edit in the question, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another font icon from [here](http://www.socicon.com/download.php).

CSS : `<link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/n6vo44Re5QaWo8oCKShBs7/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">`

icon : http://www.socicon.com/chart.php

Facebook : `class="socicon-facebook" \E041 • #3e5b98`
Twitter : `class="socicon-twitter" \E040 • #4da7de`
Instagram : `class="socicon-instagram" \E057 • #000000`
Youtube : `class="socicon-youtube" \E051 • #e02a20`

For More Click [Here](http://www.socicon.com/chart.php)